# how can I get a series of number for my answer, *not only the last number

Tags: r, function

Here is my code,the answer of odtest(x) is only "odd", how can I get a series of number from 5 to 25 for my answer ?

In manually the answer should be "odd",6,"odd",8.........24,"odd"

*function and if else have to be used. Thanks !!!

```
x=5
odtest=function(x){
for(i in x:(x+20){
if(i%%2>0){i="odd"}
}
return(i)}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution:

```
x=5
odtest <- function(y){
    ifelse(y %% 2 > 0, "odd", y)
}

sapply(x:(x+20), odtest)
[1] "odd" "6"   "odd" "8"   "odd" "10"  "odd" "12"  "odd" "14"  "odd" "16"  "odd" "18"  "odd" "20"  "odd" "22"  "odd" "24"  "odd"
```

The problem with your attempt is that your `for` loop overwrites the answer for each value of x it evaluates, and then returns only the final answer.  You need to return a vector or a list.  If you want to hide the `sapply` from the end user, you can define a wrapper function:

```
wrapperFunction <- function(x) {
  sapply(x:(x+20), odtest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the odd values with direct assignment.

```
odtest=function(x){
  x1 <- x:(x+20)
  x1[x1 %% 2 > 0] <- 'odd'
  x1
}

odtest(5)
# [1] "odd" "6"   "odd" "8"   "odd" "10"  "odd" "12"  "odd" "14"  "odd" "16"  "odd"
#[14] "18"  "odd" "20"  "odd" "22"  "odd" "24"  "odd"
```